# How safe is using .= operator on an uninitialized variable?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm using some premium plugins, and analyzing their code I found, that in some functions they use code like:

`$output .= $some_str;`

when that $output wasn't mentioned anywhere before.

How safe is this code? I tried to find any guidance in PHP Manual for this, but for what I see, they only define it for both $output and $some_str being previously set before.

Later this $output variable is used to echo HTML code.

Did you see any specifications regarding that? Maybe there is something I could do outside of those plugins to make this code safer? Some default value defined for all uninitialized variables?

Thank you!

Comment: What's your definition of "safe"? Apart from the implied NULL value and notice/warning (or log entry thereof), scripting languages aren't prone to e.g. null pointer errors. It's coverd in http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php#example-112 btw.

Comment: @mario, I meant for example, would this HTML code that variable would produce later, contain anything that wasn't intentionally put there.

Comment: The cases that you should be wary of aren't those with *uninitialized* variables then. Those won't do any harm. For plugins or themes it's possible to accidentally reuse *inherited* variables, e.g. from a shared (global) variable scope. Which might cause unintended output etc.

Comment: thank you, @mario!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is bad practice, which is why PHP will issue an E_NOTICE (if you enable error reporting).

That said, PHP variables are always initialized automatically so it won't have any negative effect.